# How create a role for long running glue redshift job?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, amazon-iam, aws-glue

A long running glue jobs for exporting data from Redshift to s3 are failed du to `S3ServiceException:The provided token has expired`. Amazon describes using a custom role as workaround ([here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/redshift/latest/dg/copy-usage_notes-access-permissions.html#copy-usage_notes-iam-permissions)). But they do not provide any example. Could somebody provide a cloudformation snipped? What a role should looks like? If I uses glue job should I add action for dynamodb or EMR cluster into Role policy?

Comment: You ever figure out this issue? Running into right now and aws docs are weak

Comment: I am also facing the same problem now. Any solution to this?